# SQL for selecting a cluster of records from a huge table with optimum SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to paginate using MS SQL Server 2005 in one of my ASP net applications. To fetch 10 records from the employee table I'm running the following SQL.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
                SELECT EmployeeID,
                       [Name],
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmployeeID ASC) AS RowNo
                FROM   Employee
            ) SELECT *
              FROM   CTE WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

The problem with this is my employee table is having 100 thousands of records and since I'm running the above query it is taking lot time. I have seen in MySQL that there is a phrase called LIMIT to limit the select record count.

Kindly help me to fetch a particular number of records records without using Common Table Expression and without running a query like the above one. I would like to know if there is a better way than this.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your `Employee` table? What ranges are the problem? Is even `BETWEEN 11 AND 20` slow or do you get the problem with much higher numbers?

Comment: @MartinSmith, the EmployeeID is my Primary key and is an Integer. Even to fetch 11 to 20 records I'm facing the performance problem. The problem is much larger when I try to fetch higher numbers. The Employee table has many foreign keys (at least 6).

Comment: Creating a duplicate non clustered index on `EmployeeId` and rewriting the query will help with the higher pages but maybe you have a blocking problem as for lower pages the query in your question should be perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your query on a table with 150.000 rows, I tried with on a column with an index and one without an index. Both was less than 1 second execution time. I imagine you have a different problem.

Since I imagine your problem lies elsewhere, I surgest you try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
            SELECT EmployeeID, 
                   [Name], 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmployeeID ASC) AS RowNo 
            FROM   Employee WITH (NOLOCK)
        ) SELECT * 
          FROM   CTE WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```